# iOS 7 notification bright up the screen but randomly show up

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I send push notification on iOS devices, but when the screen is locked, it just get brighter, but doesn't show always the push notification

I cannot figure out the pattern

Push notification is OK, and shows sometimes on one device, but not on the others (the other devices bright up the screen)

Setting are OK, different 4 iOS iPad devices
Notifications are correctly delivered to Apple

**UPDATE**

**Note: this random behaviour only seems to happen when the Badge number is 0 and send as 0 (doesn't happen when badge number is not part of the push, or > 0)**

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: `just get brighter` this is really weird, what exactly gets brighter? any screen shot?. please show how you are sending the json playload.

Comment: yup, just the screen gets brighter, but no notification is showing up, but only in case when the badge number is 0

Comment: please show me how you are sending the data to Apple Server? we will get this sorted out